# When resizing my contentpane the optel gets larger

Tags: java, swing

When I resize my contentpane, panel, however you call it, my variable optel gets larger by dragging it smaller or bigger? Why is that and how fix it? I am making the Dutch 'Ganzenbord' game. I also need an option to say; player 1 gamble the dice, player 2's turn is, throw the dice.

```
package Opdrachten;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.*;

public class spel extends JPanel {
private JButton knop;
private boolean geklikt;
private boolean player1, player2;
Random rand = new Random();
int waarde = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // De plus een is zodat je geen 0 krijgt
int optel = 0;

public spel() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    knop = new JButton("Gooi!");
    knop.addActionListener(new KnopHandler());
    add(knop);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    if(geklikt) {
        optel += waarde;
        g.drawString("Je hebt " + waarde + " gegooid. Dit is totaal:" + optel, 100, 70);

        if (waarde ==  1) {
            g.drawString("Je mag 1 vakje naar voren", 100, 90);
        }
        if (waarde ==  2) {
            g.drawString("Je mag 2 vakjes naar voren", 100, 90);
        }
        if (waarde ==  3) {
            g.drawString("Je mag 3 vakjes naar voren", 100, 90);
        }
        if (waarde ==  4) {
            g.drawString("Je mag 4 vakjes naar voren", 100, 90);
        }
        if (waarde ==  5) {
            g.drawString("Je mag 5 vakjes naar voren", 100, 90);
        }
        if (waarde ==  6) {
            g.drawString("Je mag 6 vakjes naar voren", 100, 90);
        }
    }

    if (optel == 6) {
        optel = 12;
        g.drawString("Ga verder naar 12", 100, 120);
    }
    if (optel == 19) {
        g.drawString("Sla een beurt over", 100, 120);
    }
    if (optel == 31) {
        g.drawString("Wie hier komt moet er blijven tot een andere speler er komt. Degene die er het eerst was speelt dan verder.", 100, 120);
    }
    if(optel == 42){
        optel = 39;
        g.drawString("Terug naar 39", 100, 120);
    }
    if(optel == 52){
        g.drawString("Drie beurten overslaan", 100, 120);
    }
    if(optel == 58){
        optel = 0;
        g.drawString("Terug naar het begin, opnieuw beginnen", 100, 120);
    }
    if(optel == 63){
        g.drawString("Wie hier als eerste komt heeft gewonnen", 100, 120);
    }
}

class KnopHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        geklikt = true;
        waarde = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // get another random number
        repaint();

    }
}

}
```

Comment: Question tags changed: the question has nothing to do with Eclipse and all to do with Swing.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you've got program logic and state-change code, here `optel += waarde;`, within a Swing painting method, here paintComponent. Understand that you do not have full control over when or even if this method gets called, that it will get called during any component re-size or re-draw, and so you should never have program logic or state-change code within this method. That code goes elsewhere, and paintComponent should be used for painting and painting only.

My guess is that the `optel += waarde;` should be within your ActionListener, but because I do not know what your program is doing, this is just a guess.